# virtualenv setup OSerror -5 with relocated Python on MacOSX

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I downloaded Canopy and set it as system default python(2.7) on my MacOSX El Capitan. When i was trying to use command "virtualenv ENV" from software virtualenv, I got OSerror -5.

I managed to find the cause online, but without solution. Does anyone have solution to this? If not, i have to use the python come with OS, which does not contain various useful scientific libs.

[Cause of the problem](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/822)

Comment: Don't add things like "SOLVED" to the title, when you accept an answer, the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found the best way to use virtualenv with minimal modification is always pointing python executable to the python that comes with OS X.
In my case, for example, is to use 
`~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python new_env`

Comment: The thing about that though, is that if you want to use the Canopy tools and iPython then you lose that when pointing to the OS X version.  Using Anaconda presented similar problems, but the Continuum folks have created a solution.  Check the Canopy docs to see if they have also developed a way to deal with this.

Comment: @foszter, i notice that if i use `--system-site-packages`, the numpy package that installed via Canopy is also included. I think those packages go along with virtualenv(which is canopy in my case), not python(which is system python in my case).